Alternatives to a different type of shower flooring?
I have this shower floor from one of my rental properties in which the previous owner put in. It's located in the basement (40"L x 46"W) and connects to an ejector pump and leads to the main sewage line, with the drain at the center. Any ideas to alternate flooring I could use for the shower and put in myself? The current shower floor is succumbing to mold in which I've had to clean before. Thanks


What you have is just a deck over the floor.  If you are tired of cleaning it, remove it.
What you need to do then is dependant on what is under it.

Whats underneath is just a concrete slab

Where does the water drain?
